# Precise adjustable low current source with up to 80V voltage capability

Tags: current-source

I am thinking of an adjustable constant current source that can supply 1 micro to 10 milli Amps to 16S coin cell battery pack with maximal voltage of ~80V. I need it to be precise enough: ideally not more than couple percent, but may consider up to 10% for starter.
I am planning to have USB power input to the board (5V DC), but can change this to anything else that is not too crazy (9V, 12V DC etc).

Per @Andy aka's suggestion adding the block diagram with voltage boost and variable current source.

[image: block diagram]

Also, if 1 µA is difficult to achieve, I would consider 10 µA as a minimal controllable current if this makes a difference for precision.

Please recommend ICs and circuits for V boost and I source. Thank you

Comment: is it OK if it's simply a current *sink* instead of a source? That's usually a bit easier!

Comment: You need to start with a supply of maybe +82 volts. This can be derived using a boost converter from the 5 volts or 12 volts. Then you'll need a variable current source powered from that supply but, first things first, you probably have to do some more work here to put these ideas together because asking for suggestions of a circuit falls into the trap of asking for opinions and, opinion soliciting questions tend to be closed-down. So, please add a block diagram of what I've suggested (if you understand what I said).

Comment: thanks Andy. Added the diagram per your suggestion

Comment: If you want an answer, you need to provide more details: can the negative side be floating or it has to be grounded (or connected to supply's negative rail), does the circuit need to have a very low quiescent current or is up to 10mA acceptable, etc. More details helps.

Comment: Everything grounded. Power consumption is not important, sleep and operating currents can be high